# Where am I wrong in the loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

It is supposed to print multiplication table of number 1-10.

```
<script>
    //Multiplication table of 1 to 10;
        var a=b=1;
        for (a==1; a<=10; a++){
            for(b==1; b<=10; b++){
                document.write(a + "x" + b + "=" + (a*b) + "<br />");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: For one thing, you're using matching operators versus setting operators in your for loop... use `a=1` and `b=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `a==1` and `b==1` to `a=1` and `b=1`. `==` is a comparison sign.

Comment: @ManuKarki, and update variables declaration. It should be `var a, b;`. Your version `var a = b =` makes `b` global. And you don't need to assign value here.

Answer (score 0):

there will be only single equal to sign in for loop

```
//Multiplication table of 1 to 10;
 var a=b=1;
 for (a=1; a<=10; a++){
     for(b=1; b<=10; b++){
         document.write(a + "x" + b + "=" + (a*b) + "<br />");
     }
  }
```